# Postgres - join a table with data on certain dates to a table with all dates in a range

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join, range

I have a table, 'dailymetrics' with data on certain dates. I want to join it with a table with all dates in a range so that I can then average over a date range. I'm trying to generate the date range I want and then do a left outer join with the table 'dailymetrics'. However, the output only includes dates that already exist in the 'dailymetrics' table. How do I get the output table to include all dates in the range?

**The Query**

```
SELECT day::date, dm.person_id, dm.latency
FROM generate_series('2015-08-01', '2015-08-10', INTERVAL '1 day') day
LEFT OUTER JOIN sleeptracking_dailymetrics as dm
ON dm.date=day
ORDER BY dm.person_id, day DESC;
```

**sample of current output:**

```
   day     | person_id |    latency    
------------+-----------+---------------
2015-08-08 |       847 |            56
2015-08-06 |       847 |            60
2015-08-05 |       847 |            88
2015-08-04 |       847 |            46
2015-08-03 |       847 |            24
2015-08-01 |       847 |             0
```

Rows for 2015-08-07 and 2015-08-02 aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have more than one person in the data and you oversimplified your query.  You need to do a cross join between the days and the people and *then* do a `left join`:

```
SELECT day::date, p.person_id, dm.latency
FROM (select distinct person_id from sleeptracking_dailymetrics) p cross join
     generate_series('2015-08-01', '2015-08-10', INTERVAL '1 day') day left join
     sleeptracking_dailymetrics dm
     ON dm.date = day and dm.person_id = p.person_id
ORDER BY p.person_id, day DESC;
```

The `cross join` generates all the rows.  The `left join` then brings in the data you want.

Comment: I do have more than one person in the data, but I'm getting the exact same output with your suggestion.

Comment: It works if you:
`ORDER BY p.person_id, day DESC;`

Thanks for the help!